# Error with my Spring Controller

Tags: javascript, java, ajax

This is my ajax call:

```
$.ajax({ 
    type: "GET", 
    url: "/support-web/downloadCSV.json", 
    data:jsonfile, 
    dataType:"json",
    success: function (data) { 
        console.log("SUCCESS")
    }
});
```

This is my controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/downloadCSV")
public class DownloadCSVController {
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public void downloadCSV(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, @RequestParam String json)
            throws IOException {
     ...
   }
}
```

I have this error:

> http://localhost:8080/support-web/downloadCSV?json=%5B%22http%3A%2F%2Fmapsr…ERSION%3D1.1.0%26OUTPUTFORMAT%3DCSV%26TYPENAME%3DP_GIS_OBSLITHO_MEXP%22%5D
>   404 (Introuvable)

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
   @Controller
    public class DownloadCSVController {    
            @RequestMapping(@RequestMapping(value = "/downloadCSV")", method=RequestMethod.GET)
            @ResponseBody
            public void downloadCSV(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, @RequestParam String json)
                    throws IOException {
             ...
           }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are making an ajax request to

```
"/support-web/downloadCSV.json"
```

But your controller only has     `@RequestMapping(value = "/downloadCSV")`

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/support-web")
public class DownloadCSVController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/downloadCSV", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public void downloadCSV(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, @RequestParam String json)
            throws IOException {
     ...
   }
}
```

And change ajax call to

```
$.ajax({ 
    type: "GET", 
    url: "/support-web/downloadCSV", 
    data: "json=" + jsonfile, 
    success: function (data) { 
        console.log("SUCCESS")
    }
});
```

Comment: try changing url in ajax call to "/support-web/downloadCSV" and removing datatype:json

Comment: Work but i have nothing in my `String json`

Comment: Try changing the ajax call, change data:jsonfile to data: "json=" + jsonfile

Comment: can you write me the example i don't understand please

Comment: Unexpected token +

Comment: Should work, but you could try ("json=" + jsonfile) instead

Comment: i have nothing in my String json

Comment: are you sure the jsonfile variable contains data?

Comment: this is my line in my ajax `var jsonfile={json:JSON.stringify(sourcesToCall)};`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122992/discussion-between-mercer-and-janar).